# mySQL nested SELECT problems

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with nested SELECT
I get the following error message: "select is not valid at this position for this server version expecting '(' with"

```
SELECT group_id, count (student_id) 
FROM
(
SELECT student.group_id, student.student_id, AVG(mark)
    FROM
    student, group, result
    WHERE
        student.student_id = result.student_id 
        and
        student.group_id = group.group_id
        GROUP BY student.group_id, student.student_id
) AS ”p”
p.AVG > 4
GROUP BY group_id
ORDER BY count (student_id) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

and I don't understand how to fix it. Please help me!

Thank's in advance for your answer

Comment: What is this thing alone: `p.AVG > 4`. Don't you forget the `WHERE` clause? Also, add an alias to `AVG(mark)` and use [JOINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) instead of comma separated tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by fixing two things:

- `group` is a reserved word. If you use it for a table name (try not to) you need to quote it.
- Name to the expression `AVG(mark)` as `avg_mark`.
- Add the `WHERE` clause.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT group_id, count (student_id) 
FROM
(
SELECT student.group_id, student.student_id, AVG(mark) as avg_mark
    FROM
    student, `group`, result
    WHERE
        student.student_id = result.student_id 
        and
        student.group_id = `group`.group_id
        GROUP BY student.group_id, student.student_id
) p
WHERE avg_mark > 4
GROUP BY group_id
ORDER BY count (student_id) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I will also recommend using `JOINS` for the inner query, since it can be done with `JOINS`, or at least an explicit `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful.
the problem was mostly with "group" word